# Working with Checkbox in Delphi

Tags: delphi, checkbox

My problem is like below, so I want all the checkboxes Bold,Italic and Underline to work out if I checked all of them.

I try searching similar problem from this site to help me but their question just to confusing..

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Checkbox1.Checked = True then
  Label1.Font.Style := [fsBold] else
  Label1.Font.Style := [];
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckBox2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Checkbox2.Checked = True then
  Label1.Font.Style := [fsItalic] else
  Label1.Font.Style := [];
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckBox3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Checkbox3.Checked = True then
  Label1.Font.Style := [fsUnderline] else
  Label1.Font.Style := [];
end;

end;
```

Answer (score 11):

The font style is a set of different `TFontStyle`s, so for each checkbox you need to add the respective style to the set, if it is checked or remove it, if it is unchecked, e.g.

```
if Checkbox1.Checked then
  Label1.Font.Style := Label1.Font.Style + [fsBold]; 
else
  Label1.Font.Style := Label1.Font.Style - [fsBold]
```

PS: You should always use Boolean values directly and not compare them to `True`/`False`

Comment: got it. In another question I had explain little bit more about Enumerable type. Maybe is something useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943107/how-to-hide-multiple-tabs-in-ttabcontrol/43946736#43946736